# Deploy simple PHP website to Swisscom Application Cloud: how to configure the server?

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev, php-builtin-server

I am trying to deploy a simple PHP website to the [Swisscom Application Cloud](https://developer.swisscom.com/), based on cloud foundry.

My website is working fine locally, served by Apache.

I have followed the [tutorial](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/tutorial-php/index.html), but I am not clear on some aspects.

In the tutorial, the way to check if the app is working normally is to run it in the built-in web server in php through `php -S`. This doesn't work for me because my website has `html` extensions for `php` files and these are not interpreted correctly by the built-in server. In Apache, I can configure that just fine in the `httpd.conf` file, but here I don't know how to configure such a behaviour.

That's fine by me, because I can still check the website locally serving via Apache. The problem is that it looks that in the cloud this is the way to run the app as well, although I couldn't find more info in the documentation.

I'd be surprised that this is how the app is run in production because [the php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) states the following about the built-in server:

> "It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be
> used on a public network."

Are the web apps being run on Apache in the Swisscom Application Cloud? If yes, how do I get access to configure the `httpd.conf` and `php.ini` files? If no, how can I configure the special behavior I need for my app?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a sample php app which summarizes what I am trying to achieve: deploy it in cloud foundry interpreting html files as php files.

https://github.com/atineoSE/sample-php-app-cloudfoundry

Following @daniel-mikusa 's links to documentation I added special config related to the mime types under `.bp-config/httpd/extra/httpd-mime.conf`. This doesn't work as expected, though. Accessing from firefox, I am prompted to download the file. It works fine when I serve it locally via Apache with the same directive in the `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: can you post your code or snippets here or on GitHub and link it? We don't know how your App looks (what is a simple web site?).

Answer (score 5):

The PHP build pack does not use `php -s`.  I suppose that you could, but it's not the default.  The default setup is to use PHP-FPM & Apache HTTPD, or ou can optionally use PHP-FPM w/Nginx.

For the most part, the PHP build pack should just run your app.  There are occasionally [things you need to adjust](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html#options), and they are easily configurable by adding `.bp-config/options.json` to the root of your app.

I don't know anything about your app though, so I can't really say.  If you can't get what you need with `options.json` you can customize the configuration for HTTPD, Nginx or PHP too.  Check out the docs here for instructions to do that.

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html#engine-configurations

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tips @daniel-mikusa, I am working through the docs and the error logs, making slow progress...